# My radio change event is triggered only at first in the application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a quiz app and i want the score to update. The change event for radio button in not triggered on clicking next question.
https://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/BRepQz

```
// JavaScript Document

var quiz = { "JS" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "question" : "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?",
        "options" : [
            {"a": "&lt;script&gt;", 
             "b":"&lt;javascript&gt;", 
             "c":"&lt;scripting&gt;", 
             "d":"&lt;js&gt;"}
            ],
        "answer":"&lt;script&gt;",
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "question" : "What is the correct JavaScript syntax to change the content of the HTML element below.",
        "options" : [
            {"a": " document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';", 
             "b":" document.getElementByName('p').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';", 
             "c":" document.getElement('p').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';",
             "d":" #demo.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';"}
            ],
        "answer":" document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';",
    }
    ]
}
```

var quizApp = function() {

```
this.score = 0;     
this.qno = 1;
this.currentque = 0;
var totalque = quiz.JS.length;


this.displayQuiz = function(cque) {
    this.currentque = cque;
    if(this.currentque <  totalque) {
        $("#qid").html(this.qno++);


        $("#question").html(quiz.JS[this.currentque].question); 
         $("#question-options").html("");
        for (var key in quiz.JS[this.currentque].options[0]) {
          if (quiz.JS[this.currentque].options[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //console.log(key + " -> " + quiz.JS[this.currentque].options[0][key]);
            $("#question-options").append(
                "<div class='form-check option-block'>" +
                "<label class='form-check-label'>" +
                          "<input type='radio' class='form-check-input' name='option'   id='q"+key+"' value='" + quiz.JS[this.currentque].options[0][key] + "'>" +
                              quiz.JS[this.currentque].options[0][key] +
                         "</label>"
            );
          }
        }
    } else {
        return alert("Your score: " + this.score) ; 
    }
}

this.checkAnswer = function(option) {
    var answer = quiz.JS[this.currentque].answer;
    option = option.replace(/\</g,"&lt;")   //for <
    option = option.replace(/\>/g,"&gt;")   //for >
    console.log(answer);
    console.log(option);

    if(option ==  quiz.JS[this.currentque].answer) {
        this.score = this.score + 1;
        console.log(this.score);
    }
}   

this.changeQuestion = function(cque) {
        this.currentque = this.currentque + cque;
        this.displayQuiz(this.currentque);  

}
```

}

var jsq = new quizApp();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jsq.displayQuiz(0);     
        $('input[type=radio][name=option]').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    if (this.checked) {
        jsq.checkAnswer(this.value);
    }
});

});




$('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        jsq.changeQuestion(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only applying the event handler on the elements that are already present, and not on the one that will be created later.

The event handler should be on an element that is a parent to all the future elements.

Like this:

```
$('#question-options').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=option]', function(e) {
  // code
});
```

From jQuery documentation on [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, [...] use delegated events to attach event handlers.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.